# Fonts to be used on a catalogue

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, typography, ebook

Is it safe to use any font (like Futura/Circular/Univers) on a catalogue that is going to be used only in a digital format (like an ebook) and also that is going to be sent in an EDM?
I am doing it in indesign and it's going to be exported as an interactive pdf.

Comment: How do you mean safe? It’s not going to attack you, if that’s what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on your license. If you use any typeface without having the proper license, you are breaking copyright laws.

You license text should describe whether you can use a typeface like this. Try and find out what license you have for the typeface you want to use.